# Strange NullReferenceException that I can't seem to understand

Tags: sqlite, exception, reference, null, unity-game-engine

Okay, let me explain myself:

I'm trying to code a save/load save system using SQLite with Unity, and I'm having a problem adding the loaded data to its respective List.

The thing is, if I call this code outside that method, it works. But I need it to run when data is loaded.

```
void AddPaso(string danceName)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < loadedDances.Count; i++)
    {
        if (loadedDances[i].danzaName == danceName)
        {
            try
            {
                Debug.Log(loadedDances.Count);
                loadedDances[i].pasos.Add(paso);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.Log(ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If I don't pass through all the List and I add the data using loadedDances[0] instead of [i] it works. But I don't seem to understand why, because if I print the loadedDances.Count on console, it effectively says it's greater than 0.

Why is this not working?

Comment: Thank you very much for keeping the exception (and especially the line number) a secret.

Comment: because loadedDances[i].pasos==null -> its not referring to an existing List. You probably only set the first in the array correctly.

Comment: Oops, the line that gives the NullReferenceException is the one that has loadedDances[i].pasos.Add(paso); It might be the frustration what made me forget to detail this :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently **loadedDances[i].paso** is null.

You should change it to:

```
void AddPaso(string danceName)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < loadedDances.Count; i++)
    {
        if (loadedDances[i].danzaName == danceName)
        {
            try
            {
               Debug.Log(loadedDances.Count);
               if(loadedDances[i].pasos!=null)
               {
                   loadedDances[i].pasos.Add(paso);
               }
               else
               {
                   Debug.Log ( "loadedDances["+i+"].pasos is not set correctly");
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.Log(ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
```

}

Comment: That was indeed the problem, @Rudolfwm was also correct. I fixed it, thankyu very much!!